# Contact Picker not working

Tags: ios, iphone

I want to get contact no on label when user tap on phone no . But my code taking first phone no automatically. I am using this

```
- (void)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker  didSelectPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
{
    [self getPeopleContactProperties:person:0];
}

- (void)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker didSelectPerson:(ABRecordRef)person property:(ABPropertyID)property identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier
{
    [self getPeopleContactProperties:person:identifier];
}

- (void)peoplePickerNavigationControllerDidCancel:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker;
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
- (void)getPeopleContactProperties :(ABRecordRef)person :(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier
{
     NSString *email;
       ABMultiValueRef emails = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
    if (emails) {
        CFIndex index;
        if (identifier == 0) {
            index = 0;
        } else {
            index = ABMultiValueGetIndexForIdentifier(emails, identifier);
        }
        email = (__bridge NSString *) ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(emails,index);
    }

    resultlabel.text =email;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ([peoplePicker respondsToSelector:@selector(setPredicateForSelectionOfPerson:)])
{
     peoplePicker.predicateForSelectionOfPerson = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K.@count > 1", ABPersonPhoneNumbersProperty];
}
```